# Convergence of $n\log(|\sin(n)|)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Bonjour.

Let $a_n=n\log(|\sin(n)|)$ and $s_n=\sum{a_n}$.
Study the convergence of $a_n$ and $s_n$.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: For a series to converge, terms must tend to 0 in absolute value, and $a_n$ doesn't.

Comment: @Dzoooks we don’t know yet where the term tends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** If $\sin(n) \simeq 1$ then $\sin(n+1)$ is far from 1.

Use this to deduce that for each $n$ either $n \log(|\sin(n)|)$ or $(n+1) \log(|\sin(n+1)|)$ is not close to $0$.

Can $n \log(|\sin(n)|)$ converge to 0?

**Added** Hint 2:
$$\sin(n+1)-\sin(n)=2\sin(\frac{1}{2}) \cos(n+\frac{1}{2} )\\
 \cos(n+\frac{1}{2} )=\cos(n)\cos(\frac{1}{2})-\sin(n)\sin(\frac{1}{2})$$

Now, if $|\sin(n)| \geq 1-\epsilon$ then
$$\cos^2(n) \leq 2\epsilon +\epsilon^2 \\
| \cos(n+\frac{1}{2} )| \geq |\sin(n)\sin(\frac{1}{2})|-| \cos(n)\cos(\frac{1}{2})| \geq (1-\epsilon) |\sin(\frac{1}{2})|-\sqrt{2\epsilon +\epsilon^2}|\cos(\frac{1}{2})|\\
\left| \sin(n+1)- \sin(n)\right| \geq ....\\
$$

Comment: Yes that is main idea, but how to do it rigorously

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE see edit... let me know if u need more details

Comment: I’ve seen that. A friend of mine gave me this exercise saying this was a good application of rational approximation theorem.